# Python: Regex doesn't find match

Tags: python, regex

I want to isolate the `117.5` after `Final score:` using regex in a multi-line string:

```py
string = '''Shots Fired: 146 pra 131 Kills: 131
Shots Hit: 131 L=Xo¥s11o) (sam U} Deaths: O
89.73% 89.73 100%
Final Score: 117.5 “scone
Previous High Score: 115.2'''
 m = re.search("Final score :[^ ]*", string)
if m:
   print(m.group(1))
```

I seem to be doing everything I should, but nothing gets printed. Apparently `m` is `null` and it doesn't find anything in my string. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "*redex*" Do you mean [tag:regex]?

Comment: yes, edited, sorry

Comment: Use a capturing group `^Final Score: (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` https://regex101.com/r/HewXEY/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matching `[^ ]*` matches 0+ times any char except a space which is a broad match.

You could make the match more specific matching the number with an optional decimal part and surround it with a capturing group.

Also note that you used a small caps s and the space and the colon are reversed.

If the match is at the start of the line, use an anchor `^` and `re.MULTILINE`

```
^Final Score: (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HewXEY/1/)

*Example code*

```
import re

string = '''Shots Fired: 146 pra 131 Kills: 131
Shots Hit: 131 L=Xo¥s11o) (sam U} Deaths: O
89.73% 89.73 100%
Final Score: 117.5 “scone
Previous High Score: 115.2'''
m = re.search(r"^Final Score: (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)", string, re.MULTILINE)

if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

*Output*

```
117.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with your code:

1. The pattern you're using matches `Final score :` when the label in the sample you provided is `Final Score:` (capital `S`, no whitespace before the colon (`:`)). Instead, match the label `Final Score:`
2. Array-like structures are zero-indexed in Python. Index `0` will correspond to the first match, index `1` the second, and so on and so forth. You're attempting to access `m.group(1)`, which in your example will not yield anything (there are no capture groups defined, so everything will be in `m.group(0)`).
3. You haven't "isolated" your numerical figure in a capture group. Enclose the part of the pattern used to match your number figure in parenthesis (`()`) to denotate the capture group.

Your code should look something more like this:

```
import re

string = '''Shots Fired: 146 pra 131 Kills: 131
Shots Hit: 131 L=Xo¥s11o) (sam U} Deaths: O
89.73% 89.73 100%
Final Score: 117.5 “scone
Previous High Score: 115.2'''
m = re.search('Final Score: ([^ ]*)', string)
if m:
   print(m.group(1))
```

<sup>[Repl.it](https://repl.it/@esqew/FrontAdequateProcedurallanguage)</sup>

Comment: This results prints not only the isolated '117.5' but 'Final Score: 117.5'. Wrong answer. Try to use positive lookbehind pattern to isolate the desired answer: `pattern = re.compile("(?<=Final Score: )[\d.]*?\s")`

Comment: @HenriqueBranco Good point - I've updated to reflect this requirement

Comment: Great job @esqew